# Cannot read property 'findOne' of undefined when require Models to both

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, require

i get this error after i required User to the page(i do not know what to call 'route' ? 'package'?)
that has required Shift from that page .

the error : `TypeError: Cannot read property 'findOne' of undefined`

Here is my User page

```
    const shift = require('./shift');
    const Shift = shift.shift ;

    const userSchema = new Schema({
    customerPhone: String
    });
    var User = mongoose.model('user', userSchema );

    module.exports = {
          user: User,
          router: router
       };
```

Here is my Shift page

```
    const user = require('./user');
    const User = user.user ;

    const shiftSchema = new Schema({
    customerPhone: String
    });
    var Shift = mongoose.model('shift', shiftSchema);

    module.exports = {
    shift: Shift,
    router: router
    };
```

It is strange that when i delete one of requires it works fine ;

so if want to use both Schemas on both pages what should i do ?

All tips will be appreciate . Thank You

Comment: Share the code that throws the error in your title

Comment: i think it is just cause of two require . because before i require user in other page it worked ok .

Comment: Please add the code from shift.js and user.js where you define your exports. Also show the code on the line with findOne call.

Comment: @alireza Why post the question here if you've figured it all out? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: because i know what causes the problem but do not know how to fix it in logical way . the easiest  way is that i transfer User.findOne codes to shift page . but i wanted to know better way . ok?

Comment: The language is case-sensitive by the way. Are you sure you have the names right?

Comment: @AluanHaddad yes . 100% correct .

Comment: Show user or shift. You may not have exported in accordance with your import

Comment: its 1000 line . believe me i did everything like always.

Comment: Well, one of them has to be evaluated first. It's a circular dependency problem. The evaluation of one module requires the other. Until that happens it doesn't export in its own right. So shift can't be exported without user and user can't be exported without shift

Comment: @AluanHaddad so what should i do ?

Comment: There are a few possibilities. You can use a module format that has manifest support for circular dependencies. ECMAScript modules are now fully implemented on node and are no longer under an experimental flag but officially supported. You can stick with CommonJS but use it more judiciously. For example, by only using `module.exports = valueToExport`. You can then use property accessors. A better approach whoever is simply remove the circularity. I don't know what that would take since I don't know how your modules actually use each other only that they do but it is the best option